# An inequality involving fractional laplacian

Tags: real-analysis, integration, fractional-calculus

I have to prove that for $s\in(0,1)$ and $\phi\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, ($\phi$ is a Schwartz's function):
$$|(-\Delta)^s \phi(x)|\leq c_{n,s}|x|^{-n-2s}, \quad\forall x\in\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus B_1(0),$$
for some $c_{n,s}>0$. Can you give a me a proof or some reference where i can find the proof.
Any help would be appreciated.Where, for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$:
$$ (-\Delta)^s \phi(x)=-\frac{C(n,s)}{2}
\int_{\mathbb{R^n}}\frac{\phi(x+y)+\phi(x-y)-2\phi(x)}{|y|^{n+2s}}\,dy,$$
or, on the whole $\mathbb{R}^n$:
$$(-\Delta)^su=\mathcal{F}^{-1}(|\cdot|^{2s}\mathcal{F}u),$$
where $\mathcal{F}$ is the Fourier transform.

Comment: How are you defining a fractional Laplacian? The standard way I know is via a Fourier transform in which case this should be fairly tractable.

Comment: Now i have edit the question with the definition of the fractional laplacian.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at *Getting acquainted with the fractional Laplacian* by Nicola Abatangelo and Enrico Valdinoci (you can access it for free on ArXiv). The exact result you have asked for is remarked on in Equation 2.10 and proven in Appendix B.